# How to fit my data into an exponential model but with an extra constant in matlab

Tags: matlab, curve-fitting, data-fitting

Im very new to matlab, and i don't know how to fit my datapoints into a model of my choice. 
My datapoints are not completely exponential, and i would like to fit my data into a model like this: y=a*e^(bx)+c, since the data won't go against 0 for large x-values, but are going to a constant, c that is not 0.

My code for finding my data and making it to a number, and then fitting it to an exponential model is this:

```
time = datafile(61608:63907,1);
time = table2array(time);
time = datenum(time).*(24*60*60);
time = time - time(1);
conc = datafile(61608:63907,2);
conc = table2array(conc);
f = fit(time,conc,'exp1');
plot(f,time,conc)
```

I have no idea how to fit my data into a model of my own: y=a*e^(bx)+c

Comment: Do **not** [repost questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54686919/how-to-fit-data-in-to-exponential-model-in-matlab)!

Comment: @Wolfie it might make more sense to close the old question, since the repost is at least of a usable quality. But certainly one of them has got to go

Answer (score 2):

Fit is for linear functions.  Try nlfit (https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/nlinfit.html).  The "Nonlinear Regression Using Robust Options" example is basically what you have.  They have the constant in the exponent as negative but you would change modelfun to make it positive for your case.

Comment: The linked documentation states "Note: Poor starting values can lead to a solution with large residual error." Do not get discouraged if you do not immediately find a good fit to the data, it might be the starting values.

Answer (score 2):

Following the idea of Suhas C of using *nlinfit* from MATLAB's Statistics Toolbox, here's a code snippet that might serve as guide:

```
% experimental data
xe = []; % replace [] with column vector abscissa
ye = []; % replace [] with column vector ordinate

% model function ::= y=a*e^(bx)+c, coef ::= [a,b,c]
y = @(coef,x) coef(1) .* exp(coef(2).*x) + coef(3);

% initial guess for coefficients (degenerate exponential)
coef0 = [mean(ye) - min(ye), 0, min(ye)];

% do fitting
coef = nlinfit(xe, ye, y, coef0);
```

Alternatively, you might want to use *lsqnonlin* from the Optimization Toolbox. The objective function (whose norm needs to be minimized) is the residual of the model compared to the experimental data:

```
% experimental data
xe = []; % replace [] with column vector abscissa
ye = []; % replace [] with column vector ordinate

% residual function ::= r=a*e^(b*xe)+c-ye, coef ::= [a,b,c]
r = @(coef) coef(1) .* exp(coef(2).*xe) + coef(3) - ye;

% initial guess for coefficients (degenerate exponential)
coef0 = [mean(ye) - min(ye), 0, min(ye)];

% do fitting
coef = lsqnonlin(r, coef0);
```

If none if the toolboxes are available, you may fall back to the standard MATLB minimizer `fminsearch`:

```
% experimental data
xe = []; % replace [] with column vector abscissa
ye = []; % replace [] with column vector ordinate

% residual function ::= rn=||a*e^(b*xe)+c-ye||, coef ::= [a,b,c]
rn = @(coef) norm(coef(1) .* exp(coef(2).*xe) + coef(3) - ye);

% initial guess for coefficients (degenerate exponential)
coef0 = [mean(ye) - min(ye), 0, min(ye)];

% do fitting
coef = fminsearch(rn, coef0);
```

Notes:

1. It's expected that you can adapt this code to your actual data (i.e. to modify the `xe` and `ye` assignments).
2. The initial guess for the model coefficients `coef0` is very "raw." Probably you'd get a better initial approximation if you consider only the first terms of the exponential: e<sup>bx</sup> = 1 + bx + (bx)<sup>2</sup>/2 ..., and fit *that* model first. The result of simplified-model fitting will serve as initial guess for the full-model fitting. Whether this is necessary or not is a matter of experimenting with the data.
3. `fminsearch` is usually able to minimize in **R**<sup>3</sup>, but the search for a minimum might fail if the data is very noisy, or the model is inadequate for the data (e.g. fitting sinusoidal data with an exponential model), or the model itself admits multiple local minima.